# How to set a user-defined command in vscodevim

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscodevim

When I use vim, I set my custom settings in `~/.vimrc` like this:

```
command Noh noh
command NOh noh
command NOH noh
```

so that I can execute `:noh`, `:NOh` or `:NOH`, which would work just like `:nohl`.

Now I'm working with Vscode and I installed the plugin vscodevim 1.20.2. I want to make the same settings but I don't know how. I've tried as below but it's not working:

```
"vim.normalModeKeyBindingsNonRecursive": [
        {
            "before": [
                ":NOH"
            ],
            "after": [],
            "commands": [
                {
                    "command": ":nohl",
                    "args": []
                }
            ]
        }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't been able to find a method to define custom commands with VSCodeVim, but if you split the `"before"` value into an array of characters (i.e. `"before": [":", "N", "O", "H"]`), you can simulate the desired behavior. It's somewhat hacky, since the normal-mode keybindings show up in a different place in the status bar, but it seems to work for me.

Note that you also won't be able to use tab completions, since you're not defining a real Ex command, but you can use `"<Tab>"` as a key in your `"before"` array, and it works. This way, you can use your command's most commonly-typed prefix, appended with `"<Tab>"`, as the `"before"`.

Note also that VSCodeVim added [experimental `vimrc` support](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim#vimrc-support), which you could try. However, it seems like at least certain custom-defined commands [fail to work](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/issues/4454).